# MySQL optimising slow query

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I am trying to run a transaction report but it is taking more than 40sec then timeout by the server. Hope I can get some help to get it optimised.

```
select 
      test_txn.abcid, 
      txndate,
      txndate2 
   from 
      test_txn 
         inner join test_abc 
            on test_txn.abcid = test_abc.abcid 
         inner join typetest 
            on test_txn.txntypeid = typetest.id 
   WHERE 
      typetest.name = 'DAILY';
```

```
SHOW CREATE TABLE test_txn;

-- transaction table contains over 1million records 

CREATE TABLE `test_txn` (
   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `txndate` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT current_timestamp(),
   `txndate2` date DEFAULT NULL,
   `abcid` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   `txntypeid` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `txntypeid` (`txntypeid`),
   KEY `abcid` (`abcid`,`txndate`),
   CONSTRAINT `test_txn_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`txntypeid`) REFERENCES `typetest` (`id`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SHOW CREATE TABLE test_abc;
-- contains few hundreds records

CREATE TABLE `test_abc` (
   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `abcid` char(15) DEFAULT NULL,
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `abcid` (`abcid`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1

SHOW CREATE TABLE typetest;
-- a small lookup table only 20 records;
CREATE TABLE `typetest` (
   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `name` char(20) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   `payment` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
   `description` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
   PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
   KEY `txnName` (`name`)
 ) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

This is the slow report I am trying to run

```
Analyze select count(*) from test_txn inner join test_abc on test_txn.abcid=test_abc.abcid inner join typetest on test_txn.txntypeid=typetest.id WHERE typetest.name='DAILY';
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys   | key       | key_len | ref                    | rows   | r_rows      | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | typetest | ref  | PRIMARY,txnName | txnName   | 20      | const                  | 1      | 1.00        |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test_txn | ref  | txntypeid,abcid | txntypeid | 5       | residev.typetest.id    | 386642 | 10969301.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where              |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test_abc | ref  | abcid           | abcid     | 16      | residev.test_txn.abcid | 1      | 1.00        |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using index              |
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+------------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
3 rows in set (49.26 sec)
```

When I took out the join with the small lookup table it ran fine

```
 Analyze select count(*) from test_txn inner join test_abc on test_txn.abcid=test_abc.abcid;
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type  | possible_keys | key   | key_len | ref                    | rows   | r_rows    | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test_abc | index | abcid         | abcid | 16      | NULL                   | 131202 | 131304.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test_txn | ref   | abcid         | abcid | 16      | residev.test_abc.abcid | 66     | 88.23     |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using index              |
+------+-------------+----------+-------+---------------+-------+---------+------------------------+--------+-----------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (5.60 sec)
```

transaction table join with the lookup table typetest is fine

```
 Analyze select count(*) from test_txn inner join typetest on test_txn.txntypeid=typetest.id WHERE typetest.name='DAILY';
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table    | type | possible_keys   | key       | key_len | ref                 | rows   | r_rows      | filtered | r_filtered | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | typetest | ref  | PRIMARY,txnName | txnName   | 20      | const               | 1      | 1.00        |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using where; Using index |
|    1 | SIMPLE      | test_txn | ref  | txntypeid       | txntypeid | 5       | residev.typetest.id | 386642 | 10969301.00 |   100.00 |     100.00 | Using index              |
+------+-------------+----------+------+-----------------+-----------+---------+---------------------+--------+-------------+----------+------------+--------------------------+
2 rows in set (4.87 sec)
```

```
SELECT COUNT(*) from test_txn;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
| 12430021 |
+----------+
1 row in set (3.70 sec)
 SELECT COUNT(*) from test_txn where abcid IS NULL;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|   844795 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.65 sec)
```

Comment: Are there `test_txn` records without `abcid` matching in the other table? Why not just `select count(*) from test_txn`?

Comment: Where's the query?

Comment: The complete query is modified so not to reveal sensitive info. There are some other tables join to test_abc table but the main tables are test_abc and test_txn

Comment: Based on the `r_rows` and `r_filtered` columns of your EXPLAIN, I think you might be using MariaDB, not MySQL. Can you please run `SELECT VERSION();` and show what it returns?

Comment: 10.4.26-MariaDB-log

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can add one new index on the table `test_txn` , like this:

```
ALTER TABLE `test_txn`  ADD INDEX `idx_com1`(`abcid`, `txntypeid`) USING BTREE;
```

that it can using indexes when you join with three tables.

Answer (score 0):

I would rewrite based first on the table you want the data from with the filtering WHERE criteria.  Have an appropriate index to match that where clause AND the column needed to get to the next table in the joins

```
table       index
typetest    (name, id)
test_txn    (txntypeid, abcid )
test_abc    (abcid)
```

By having a single index on a table that has both (or more) columns associated with the search will allow the engine to QUALIFY the records directly from the index without having to go to the raw data pages for any other parts.

So here, you can see I start with the typeTest based on the name first since that is your WHERE condition, but then ALSO the ID as that is the lead into the Test_TXN table.  From the Test_TXN table you need that first part txnTypeId to qualify the test, but then need the ABCID for its next link down to the test_abc table.  Finally, since you indicated this is an abbreviated query due to private information, I dont see a need for anything else but the abcid column in your test_abc table.

Once the records are qualified all from the index, it can then go to the raw data pages to pull the records it needs for additional pull of columns such as your txnDate and txnDate2.

```
select 
      test_abc.abcid, 
      test_txn.txndate,
      test_txn.txndate2 
   from 
      typetest 
         inner join test_txn 
            on typetest.id = test_txn.txntypeid
            inner join test_abc 
               on test_txn.abcid = test_abc.abcid 
   WHERE 
      typetest.name = 'DAILY';
```

FEEDBACK.
Although the type-test table has the primary key of the ID, you are SEARCHING based on the name.  Yes, it is a smaller table (only 20 or so records as you indicated), but now think of it as a larger table.  You want to jump directly to the record(s) you are interested in.  Then, by having the extra column as part of the key, the engine never needs to go to the actual RECORD to join to the next level.

For the test_txn table is exactly the same principle, you are JOINING based on the key from one table, but need the corresponding key to join to the next table.  Otherwise, the engine needs to find the record based on one key, go to the raw data page to find the ID that joins to the next table, THEN join to the next table.  A lot of back-and-forth internally.  By having both parts (or more depending on your database needs), having all the critical parts on joining before and after will help improve performance.  Not every time do you need ALL columns, but at least the critical ones that make the most sense that are direct values vs "like" considerations, or those that apply multiple OR conditions, but that is something that will come with experience.

Comment: Thank you. With typetest table why do we need id to be part of the index when it is already a primary key

Comment: Similary, test_txn table, txntypeid is a foreign key to typetest so do we still need to include it as an index?

Comment: @Hannah, see revised answer for explanation.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. Another consideration is the size of test_txn over 12million rec and growing. So building a new index will take time. Would the process of building index lockup the table? When I am ready to apply the index in production environment, do I need to backup the table (including the keys) first just in case?

Comment: What is your recommendation when a huge transaction table keeps growing?

Comment: Is there any tool (other than Analyze) to diagnose query performance with MariaDB? Would be good to see the execution path

Comment: @Hannah, I dont think that doing one index on 12 million records will be too bad.  Especially if done during a low-peak time period.  Then, once it is done, it is just maintained automatically as each new record added.  Time hit at that point will be almost nothing.  Just the one big hit for the new index creation.  They are also relatively small / easy columns to index.

Comment: Thanks @DRapp. I am surprise adding index doesn't lockup the table. https://mariadb.com/kb/en/create-index/ -> "If another connection is using the table, a metadata lock is active, and this statement will wait until the lock is released. This is also true for non-transactional tables." So what do we do with transaction table growing rapidly? How can we keep it small ?

Comment: @Hannah, sorry, cant answer that, especially if system is up 24 hours a day and filling with daily activity.  Try it, take the hit now once, then your long-term querying should be much improved helping the longer term issue.

Answer (score 0):

The test_txn is a transaction table, I ended up added date range to the where clause of the query then the report ran under 20 sec :) All transaction report would have date range applied to the query for sure!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).